# how to convert an image firebase url to file object using typescript (angular 11-15)

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I get an image from firebase storage which has this link
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/developpement-fea24.appspot.com/o/partner%2Fune-station%2Flogo%2Fwk62203828-image-kp6bmcbb.jpg?alt=media&token=bffed6f9-5cac-42c8-a7b1-f27e37559493
I have tried several methods with js which make xmlrequest or fetch but it gave me nothing
Can you please give ressource or direct solution that can help resolve this problem?

Comment: It's like an image wich is not intended to be shared. In the middle of the link, we can read "partner". Contact this partner to find out what rights you have to this image.

Comment: its just the name of folder